# How to upgrade PHP to 7.4.30?

Tags: 20.04, upgrade

The default version of PHP on Ubuntu Server 20.04 is 7.4.3, I want to upgrade it to 7.4.30. I've added ppa:ondrej/php to apt repository, but apt upgrade shows it will upgrade PHP to 8.1. How can I tell apt that I don't want to skip to PHP 8?

Comment: Sorry, it's 20.04, I didn't write it completely.

Comment: Why do you want the 7.4.30?

Comment: @Pilot6, I saw a lot of bug fixes since 7.4.3, should I upgrade?

Comment: Ubuntu has a bit different versions that include bug fixes. Upgrading to alternative packages is not needed in most cases.

Comment: Ubuntu has `7.4.3-4ubuntu2.12` version that should include the fixes. see http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php7.4/php7.4_7.4.3-4ubuntu2.12/changelog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu maintainers include bug fixes and security updates in the official packages. They keep major version. So there is no need to upgrade to upstream minor releases.

You can see that Ubuntu 20.04 has the `7.4.3-4ubuntu2.12` version of PHP.

You can refer to [Changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php7.4/php7.4_7.4.3-4ubuntu2.12/changelog)

This is a frequent mistake to look for this type of "upgrades".

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr:

```
sudo apt install php7.4=1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Full explanation:

Since you've already added the `ppa:ondrej/php` repository (via `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`), you can use `apt-cache` to list the available versions that can be installed, and then `apt install` to install a specific version.

The `apt` tool uses aliases to simplify the installation of popular applications.  As you've inadvertently discovered, `apt install php` is now an alias for `apt install php8.1`.  The ondrej/php repository adds packages for `php8.1`, `php8.0`, and `php7.4`, and adds an alias for `php` that points to `php8.1`.

Because you want to install php 7.4.30, you'll need to explicitly include the version number in the `apt install` command. The `apt-cache` command will list all available versions.  I prefer using `apt-cache madison` because I find the output easier to read than `apt-cache showpkg` or `apt-cache policy`, but any of these will provide the information you need -- use whichever command you prefer.

```
apt-cache madison php7.4
```

will return something like this:

```
php7.4 | 1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
php7.4 | 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.12 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
php7.4 | 7.4.3-4ubuntu2.12 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
php7.4 | 7.4.3-4ubuntu1 | http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
```

The columns are organized like so:

```
<package name> | <version> | <repository>
```

`apt` supports installing a specific version of a package using the optional `package=version` syntax.  In this case, the desired version is `1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`, which is from the ondrej/php repository.

Putting it all together:

```
 sudo apt install php7.4=1:7.4.30-5+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```